# visual studio 2008 MFC error

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a MFC dialog created, i added a class for it, and now, every time i try to add a variable for a control of that dialog i get this error message: `Unable to update class constructor`. I have tried deleting `*.suo` files, build/rebuild/clean and over again, even deleted the `.h`  and `.cpp` files of dialog's class and added the class once more, the error persists.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happennig?

Using VS2008 SP1 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the `.nbc` and `.clw`, reopened my solution and now works just fine.